# jQuery or Javascript to set all buttons to the width of the widest button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My client would like for me to write a sliver of code, jQuery preferred, that would set ALL the links to the same width of the widest link.  Here's the HTML:

```
<div>
<h1>HEADER</h1>
<p style="text-align: right;" class="floatRight"><a href="#" class="small-button eLength"><span>BUTTON 1</span></a></p>
<p style="text-align: right;" class="floatRight"><a href="#" class="small-button eLength"><span>BUTTON 2</span></a></p>
<p style="text-align: right;" class="floatRight"><a href="#" class="small-button eLength"><span>BUTTON LONGEST</span></a></p>
</div>
```

The CSS sets all three buttons to a min-width of 180px. I'm looking for this all to hinge on the class: ***eLength***

Comment: Are the buttons and their labels being created dynamically? If they aren't I personally think adding this kind of overhead is a silly thing to do.

Comment: The buttons ARE being created dynamically

Answer (score 10):

You can get the max width like this:

```
var widest = Math.max.apply(Math, $('.eLength').map(function() { 
    return $(this).width(); 
}));
```

And to wrap this in a sliver plugin:

```
$.fn.widest = function() {
    return this.length ? this.width(Math.max.apply(Math, this.map(function() { 
        return $(this).width();
    }))) : this;
};

$('.eLength').widest();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using John Resig's [Fast JavaScript Max/Min](http://ejohn.org/blog/fast-javascript-maxmin/):

```
Array.max = function(array) {
    return Math.max.apply(Math, array);
};

var widths = new Array();
$('.eLength').each(function(index) {
    widths.push($(this).width());
});

alert("Max Width: " + Array.max(widths));
```

Comment: The alert comes up Max Width: -Infinity

Comment: Be careful with that max function, passing anything else than an array with a length will return `-Infinity`.