# Text not centered inside button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two buttons,one of the button text is not in the center of the button.

```css
.mail_download_csv_btn{
  width: 100px !important;
  font-size: 12px !important;
}

.margin_right_10{
  margin-right:10px;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info height_30 width_110  mail_download_csv_btn">Download CSV</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info height_30 width_110 margin_right_10 mail_download_csv_btn">Mail PDF</button>
```

The text **Download CSV** is not centered to the button.
Any help would be great.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is centered, just your buttons width is limited, and the text overflow on right side, change:

```
.mail_download_csv_btn{
  width: 100px !important;
  font-size: 12px !important;
}
```

to

```
.mail_download_csv_btn{
  width: 125px !important;
  font-size: 12px !important;
}
```

I were setted `width` to a 125px, if you wish to have buttons the same width, otherwise, just delete `width` tag, if you wish to be auto.

Example with larger width:

```css
.mail_download_csv_btn{
  width: 125px !important;
  font-size: 12px !important;
}

.margin_right_10{
  margin-right:10px;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info height_30 width_110  mail_download_csv_btn">Download CSV</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info height_30 width_110 margin_right_10 mail_download_csv_btn">Mail PDF</button>
```

Comment: i want both the buttons width to be same. that's why i have put width

Comment: As i said, i were just setted 125px instead of 100px

Answer (score 0):

The text is not centered because you set an explicit width to your button that simply is too small for the text.

Remove `width: 100px !important` from your `.mail_download_csv_btn` and the text gets the space needed for being centered.

[image]

If you want all buttons to have the same size, you should not set an explicit width as you can't know how much space the widest button will take in different browsers.
Instead try something like [setting all buttons to the width of the widest button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274809/jquery-or-javascript-to-set-all-buttons-to-the-width-of-the-widest-button).

Comment: i want both the buttons width to be same. that's why i have put width